# list IndexError while reading from a file in Python

Tags: python

```
file_to_read = open("gradeSubject.rtf", "r")

for line in file_to_read:
    values = line.split()
    subject = values[0]
    grade = values[1]

    print(Subject, "---------->", grade)
file_to_read.close()
```

File has two columns of data. Like this:

```
Subject     Grade
English      89
French       90
Maths        99
Science      100
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(values)` to see what it comes out with... it implies you've got a line that doesn't have at least two columns that are whitespace delimited.... (probably a blank one)

Comment: I tried printing values. It prints data, that is not in my file. ['{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1265\\cocoasubrtf190'] ['{\\fonttbl\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0', 'Helvetica;}'] {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 ----------> Helvetica;} ['{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}'] ['\\margl1440\\margr1440\\vieww10800\\viewh8400\\viewkind0'] ['\\pard\\tx720\\tx1440\\tx2160\\tx2880\\tx3600\\tx4320\\tx5040\\tx5760\\tx6480\\tx7200\\tx7‌​920\\tx8640\\pardirnatural'] I dont know what is this and how to avoid this before processing the required data.

Comment: So you have an actual RTF file then... not a plain text file... in whatever editor (wordpad/Word/OO) you're using save it/export it as plain text to remove the formatting data...

Comment: It worked after changing to plain text. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
print(Subject, "---------->", grade)
```

to

```
print(subject, "---------->", grade)
```

Comment: This might raise a `NameError`.... but certainly not an `IndexError`. Although useful to the OP - I don't think it the answers the *real question* the OP is trying to ask but only providing enough info. for best guesses :)

Comment: @JonClements Well actually, I tested the code he posted before I post my answer. The only error I got was NameError. You can test that too if you want

Comment: Yup - I'll agree that's the error if the data's correct... but since he hasn't got to that and mentioned `IndexError`, it's either 1) confusion 2) copy/paste error or most likely 3) the data isn't as the OP has shown it...

Answer (score 0):

Have it print the line before attempting to split. That'll tell you which line is failing. In these cases it's often a blank line (perhaps at the end of the file).

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you have a blank line (or at least one not containing any whitespace), therefore `.split()` returns a one-item list, and `grade = values[1]` fails because there is no `values[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to an element that does not exist. Try this:

```
for line in file_to_read:
    values = line.split()
    if len(values) > 1:
        subject = values[0]
        grade = values[1]

        print(subject, "---------->", grade)
```